# How do I use a map to reduce odometry errors? [SOLVED]

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I have a *.pgm and *.yaml map and I want to use it, somehow, to reduce the odometry errors.

I need to get accurate locations to set point on a map and someone recomended this to me. However I couldn't find info about that anywhere.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246787/how-do-i-use-a-map-to-reduce-odometry-errors?-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [jmrssc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28386/jmrssc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-08**:
@jmrssc: if you feel one of the answers provided below has actually answered your question, could you please mark it as such by ticking the checkmark to the left of it? That is much clearer than adding `[SOLVED]` to your question title.

Note that comments can be converted to answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like you are looking for a ROS package for localization: http://wiki.ros.org/amcl

Keep in mind that localizing against a map requires Laser Scan or Point Cloud data from a corresponding sensor (spinning LiDAR, MS Kinect, etc.)

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jmrssc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28386/jmrssc/) on 2016-10-30**:
Yes!
I think it is this.

Thank you!

**Comment by [krusion](https://answers.ros.org/users/28391/krusion/) on 2016-10-31**:
Well, is there a way to do it with just a camera? Our project is similar but it is outdoors. LIDAR is too expensive, and MS Kinect doesn't work with sun light. We were hoping we'd be able to use the RPi camea module. I've already looked into AprilSLAM. Haven't tried it yet.

**Comment by [trgtylcnky](https://answers.ros.org/users/28434/trgtylcnky/) on 2016-11-07**:
@krusion I think that will help: http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap